# Is there a way to remove the ARP entry after a failed WiX installation?

Tags: wix, bundle, arp

I ran into an issue that when my custom action fails during an installation that an ARP entry is still created for the bundle.  Is there a way to remove that ARP entry from Add/Remove programs? Or is this the expected behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: It's expected behaviour in that you will have inadvertently set your installer up to do so, but it is not the case that WiX installers *always* leave an ARP entry on a failed installation.

Comment: I don't understand, what would cause the installer to add an entry to ARP?

Comment: I'm not sure, but by default and installation which fails to complete should leave the machine in the same state as it found it in, so no ARP entry should be created on failure. I would assume you have an issue with the rollback on failure not executing correctly.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue, by removing the RollBackBoundary from the Bundle, as it was place after permanent packages. Thanks Calum.

Answer (score 0):

This tool from Microsoft will attempt to fix failed installation/uninstallations that still appear in the add/remove programs list.

The issue is related to orphaned or incorrect registry entries. There are a lot of references to other keys though so if you aren't thorough doing it yourself you can leave something behind that might bite you later on.

This tool is probably the safest way to fix your registry with regards to installations but it is not 100%

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed

Answer (score 0):

Bundles are registered to manage reboots and repair and the registration is not removed if any package in the chain was successful.

Comment: Do you mean unsuccessful?